# How do I design this link table?

Tags: sql, database

Ok SO, I have a user table and want to define groups of users together.  The best solution I have for this is to create three database tables as follows:

UserTable

```
user_id
user_name
```

UserGroupLink

```
group_id
member_id
```

GroupInfo

```
group_id
group_name
```

This method keeps the member and group information separate.  This is just my way of thinking.  Is there a better way to do this?  Also, what is a good naming convention for tables that link two other tables?

Comment: There's missing information here. Can a user belong in multiple groups? Is belonging to a group optional or mandatory? The solution you propose is okay, but can be trimmed down further if a user must have only one group. Also, calling it member id is inconsistent with the entity being called user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks, good, I would go with:

```
Group
-----
GroupID (PK)
Name
CreatedDate

GroupUser
---------
GroupUserID (PK)
GroupID (FK)
UserID (FK)
CreatedDate

User
----
UserID (PK)
Firstname
Lastname
CreatedDate
...
```

Comment: @Soo, FK = foreign key, a key from another table.

Comment: Wouldn't GroupId + UserId be an acceptable PK in your link table?

Comment: @Jacob, yes it would. I prefer a single surrogate key over compound keys; this is a matter of choice.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If a member can only belong to one group, then your solution is overkill (and not properly optimized). In that case it would be enough to get rid of the `UserGroupLink` table and just add a `group_id` column to `UserTable`.

Comment: Each user can be a member of multiple groups.  I should have specified that in the OP (my mistake)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a fairly standard role based user model to me. This is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to choose a convention and stick with it.

Here's how I would name these tables (the structure is fine, BTW):

```
Users
-----
id
name

UserGroups
----------
user_id
group_id

Groups
------  
id
name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table layout is appropriate, IMHO.  There are various naming conventions for the join table - Ruby on Rails uses both table names joined with an underscore, in alphabetical order: "group_member" in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers, the decision in creating tables does not rely on ones opinion. There is what we call database normalization; a rule to follow in database design.